# Dictionary filtering based on key does not works

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have the following dict:

```
ricavi={'Pergolato Recensione Completa': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200.0, 0, 150000.0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

I want to filter for key based on another variable, named `prodotto` that contains all key filtered.

```
prodotto=['Pergolato Recensione Completa']
```

How could get it?

I have tried the following code but does not work:

```
ricavi= dict((key,value) for key, value in ricavi.items() if key == prodotto)
```

Comment: ```if key == prodotto``` compares a string (key) to a list (prodotto).   perhaps ```if key in prodotto```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this (use **key in prodotto**):

```
ricavi={'Pergolato Recensione Completa': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200.0, 0, 150000.0, 0, 0, 0]} 
prodotto=['Pergolato Recensione Completa']

ricavi2= dict((key,value) for key, value in ricavi.items() if key in prodotto)
print(ricavi2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if prodotto conaint always one element:

```
ricavi= dict((key,value) for key, value in ricavi.items() if key == prodotto[0])
```

Please note `prodotto` is a list so the first element is extracted to comparison.